# Removing duplicate rows based on column while keeping the highest value of the next column

Tags: r

I'd like to remove the duplicates from column x1 and x2 while keeping the higher value from x3.

DF:

```
x1  x2  x3
 1   1   1
 1   1   2
 1   1   3
 2   2   2
 2   2   5
```

Expected result:

```
x1  x2  x3 
 1   1   3
 2   2   5
```

I've gotten as far as df[!duplicated(df[,c(1,2)]),] but it's displaying the lowest value of x3. I'd like to get the highest x3 value.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could `aggregate()`, using the first two columns for grouping

```
aggregate(x3 ~ x1 + x2, df, max)
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  1  3
# 2  2  2  5
```

If you want to find the max in more than one column, you can add variables to the left hand side of the formula with `cbind()`.  For example,

```
aggregate(cbind(x3, x4, x5) ~ x1 + x2, df, max)
```

Comment: what if i have multiple columns at the end (x4, x5)? can i specify which column to take the highest value from?

Answer (score 5):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x1,x2) %>% summarise(x3 = max(x3))
```

You could title the maximum variable "maxOfx3" or similar for clarity.

Edit: If you have additional variables whose maxima you want, you can include them in the `summarise()` call:

`df %>% group_by(x1,x2) %>% summarise(x3 = max(x3), x4 = max(x4), avg_of_x5 = mean(x5))` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another alternative with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(DF)

dt[,.SD[which.max(x3)],by=list(x1, x2)]

   x1 x2 x3
1:  1  1  3
2:  2  2  5
```